# Transferring a Website via PrintWriter

Tags: java, sockets, web

I´m wonderring myself if it is possible to host a "webserver" just with a simple socket which prints out the website via a PrintWriter.

I already tried this and for a splitsecond I can see my html code displayed but after that the connection aborts.

Please don´t hate me that there a plenty of litte webserver-solutions, I know that but I´m trying to get forward and to improve my programming skills. I appreciate every advice for better coding.

Here is my **Java** Code:

```
public class webserver {
ServerSocket serversocket=null;
Socket s=null;
OutputStream o=null;
public webserver(){

    try {
        serversocket=new ServerSocket(8080);
        writeout();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void writeout(){

    try {
        char[] cbuf=new char[100000];
        s=serversocket.accept();
        o=s.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(o);
        FileReader fr=new FileReader("C:/Users/me/Documents/HelloWorld.html");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        br.read(cbuf);  
        br.close();
        pw.write(cbuf);
        pw.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And that is my **Html** file builded by *Google Web Designer*:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>

      <head data-gwd-animation-mode="quickMode">
<title>HelloWorld</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="generator" content="Google Web Designer 1.0.3.0115">
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  body {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1400px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .gwd-div-c9x0 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 356px;
    height: 214px;
    left: 446px;
    top: 54px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman';
    text-align: left;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .gwd-div-qte5 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 73px;
    height: 59px;
    left: 781px;
    top: 54px;
  }
  .gwd-div-wq83 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 29.5px;
    left: 802px;
    top: 54px;
  }
</style>
   </head>

      <body>
       <div class="gwd-div-c9x0">Testing the Printed Website</div>
<div class="gwd-div-qte5"></div>
<div class="gwd-div-wq83"></div>
     </body>

    </html>
```

But my "webserver" terminates without an exception.

Comment: You need to learn more about Java IO, and to implement the HTTP protocol. Your code doesn't necessarily read the whole file, and if it does, your array holds 100000 chars, and not only the chars from the file. And a HTTP response is supposed to contain a status line, followed by header lines, followed by an empty line, followed by the response body. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol for a start, and the actual HTTP standard if you're really serious about it.

Comment: @JB Nizet so i should get out the number of the chairs which are contained in the html file and define this as the size of the array? Thanks I don´t know why I didn´t thougt of looking up a html answer of a server at wikipedia... I thought it would be enough to print out the html file...

Comment: No, not necessarily. `read()` doesn't guarantee to read as many bytes as the array you pass as argument. Read its javadoc. It returns the actual number of bytes that have been read. So you need to loop until all it returns -1 (which indicates EOF). And you're not forced to read everything in memory. You could read chunks of bytes and write them to the response, to avoid consuming too much memory. You'll need to send the number of *bytes* of the body in the Content-Length header though. Or to implement chunked responses.